# Calling an URL which does not return Certificate Chain using Node JS

Tags: node.js, certificate, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I am trying to call an REST URL which returns only the main certificate and not the Intermediate and Root CA. I tried adding the certificates using the below code. Both intermediate and rootca are copied into same file. But somehow this doesn't seem to work, facing the error saying "**unable to verify the first certificate**"

```
 const axios = require('axios');
    const fs = require('fs');
    var https = require('https');
    
    const httpagent = new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        ca: fs.readFileSync('path to rootCA.cer'),

    })
    //sslrootCAs.inject();
    axios.get(
        `https://REST_API_URL`, { httpagent }
    )
```

The root CA has both the intermediate and root certificate embedded in it.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by adding the certificates this way.

```
const fs = require('fs');
    
var https = require('https');
    
    sslrootCAs.addFile('Path to rootCA.cer');
    sslrootCAs.addFile('Path to intermediate.cer')
    https.globalAgent.options.ca = sslrootCAs;

const httpagent = new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false,


    })
axios.get('REST URL', {httpagent})
```